# do_shortcode with Instagram doesn't work - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, instagram

I'm trying to insert an embed post of Instagram via code using **do_shortcode** function. This is the shortcode example that Instagram gives on the embed documentation:

[instagram url=https://www.instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/ hidecaption=true width=320]

So I'm trying to call it like this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[instagram url=https://www.instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/ hidecaption=true width=320]');
```

The result I'm having is like I was using only the echo function, the shortcode comes as plain text on the browser.

The page that I'm editing is the **single.php**. And I did a test using a contact form 7 shortcode, it works normally with do_shortcode.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does it need `"`? so, `echo do_shortcode('[instagram url="https://www.instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/" hidecaption=true width=320]'); `

Comment: Also, there are many instagram plugins. Please post link to documentation for specific plugin

Comment: I have tried this one too.. Same result, plain text.

Comment: ok, is the plugin actually activated?

Comment: I'm not using any plugin for this.. It's a custom theme that I'm doing and I need to embed an Instragram video on the top of a page. So, the idea is that the admin will register an Instagram link. I'm checking if this link is not empty, if not, I will embed the video on the page.

Comment: Then have you built the function on the functions.php file that shows that shortcode? Please post your code. [instagram] is not a core piece of code, you either have to build it yourself or use the plugin.

Comment: I have to create a function inside functions.php to translate Instagram shortcodes? Shouldn't do_shortcode function do the trick?

Comment: no, because that shortcode is not magically going to appear if you are not using the plugin. see my answer about creating a shortcode. Then you can take it from there.

Comment: If this is just getting hardcoded into your template, why don't you just use the html embed code from the insta post?

Comment: The idea is that I register a Instagram post link on my admin, a video, by post. This is already happening. Now, I have to turn this link that I register on a custom field into a Instagram embed. So, I'm trying to get this link and put it inside a string wich respect this format: [instagram url=https://www.instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/ hidecaption=true width=320] only changing the url, putting my url. And after that, I'm trying to read this shortcode with the function do_shortcode. Shouln't it work?

Comment: Is the custom field a wysiwyg or just a text field?

Comment: Just a text field. But for this example, I'm not even using this custom field that I created. I'm just testing the shortcode given by the Instagram documentation about embedding content in Wordpress.

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but you are wrapping this in php tags, right? I just tested your code in a single custom post type and it worked.

Comment: Yes, it's wrapped in php tags. Did you used this example: [instagram url=instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6 hidecaption=true width=320] ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to insert this code in your pages/posts, or a template file?

For pages/posts, all you need is:

```
[instagram url="https://www.instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/" hidecaption=true width=320]
```

For template files:

```
echo do_shortcode('[instagram url="https://www.instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/" hidecaption=true width=320]')
```

Since you are not using a plugin, the shortcode has not been defined. You can either use a plugin ( https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-instagram-embed/ ) or define the shortcode using Mark's suggestion.

Comment: It's the single.php file. None of the suggestions worked.

Comment: Are you calling?

    wp_load("/path/to/your/wp_load.php")

Comment: No.. I need to do that on the single.php?

Comment: My mistake ... no ... you shouldn't have to call it on the standard single.php file

Comment: Are you using an Instagram embed plugin or simply trying to embed manually?

Comment: No plugins. I'm just trying to use the do_shortcode function on my single.php to translate this: [instagram url=https://www.instagram.com/p/bNd86MSFv6/ hidecaption=true width=320] into a instagram embed.

Comment: Mark's suggestion is still giving me plain text.

Comment: This would be the easiest solution for you:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/

Comment: Wordpress.com isn't the same as wordpress.org

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the code for `[instagram]`? Please post this code for us.

Put this in your functions.php file:

```
function my_awesome_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   echo "This is my shortcode";
}

add_shortcode( 'awesome', 'my_awesome_shortcode' );
```

now put:

```
echo do_shortcode('[my_awesome_shortcode]');
```

into your single .php file. What is the result? if you get

> This is my shortcode

Then it is working, you can use this template to build your instagram one.

Comment: I edit the functions.php with the function you said, just replaced "This is my shortcode" with the shortcode that I mentioned. After that, I called it on my single.php the way you suggested and the result is still a plain text, now with: "[my_awesome_shortcode]"

Comment: You gave me the wrong code for the single.php. I have to call do_shortcode('[awesome]'), now, it brings the content of the shortcode, but it still comes with plain text. 
When I use the shortcode example given by instagram documentation, it doesn't translate into an embedded post.